# ngx-monaco-editor is showing no Suggestions

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, angular5, monaco-editor

I went through [ngx-monaco-editor]: https://github.com/atularen/ngx-monaco-editor

Cloned the project & customizing the same - Word Suggestions are coming only for Css & JavaScript languages as they are default.But requirement is Java,Csharp editors.

Html code -

```
<ngx-monaco-editor [options]="options" [(ngModel)]="displaycode" (onInit)="onInit($event)"></ngx-monaco-editor>
```

TypeScript code -

```
options = {theme: 'vs-dark'};
onInit(editor) {
  this.editor = editor;
}
```

I tried

```
1) options = {theme: 'vs',quickSuggestions: true,wordBasedSuggestions: true};

2) Inside ngOnInit function:

this.options = Object.assign({}, this.options, {theme: 'vs',language: java});
Theme changes are reflecting & if i debug language is updated in options.

3)  updateOptions() {
     this.toggleLanguage = !this.toggleLanguage;
     if (this.toggleLanguage) {
           this.code = this.javaCode;
           this.options = Object.assign({}, this.options, { language: 'java' });
     } else {
          this.code = this.cSharpCode;
          this.options = Object.assign({}, this.options, { language: 'csharp' });
     }
```

[Image of editor showing - no Suggestions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6EeA.jpg)

i went through github links like https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/632, but didn't find any help

How can i get word Suggestion working in the editor for Java & cSharp ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for content assist support, you should look at TypeFox's [monaco-languageclient](https://github.com/TypeFox/monaco-languageclient/) project. You can then connect your Monaco editor with a C# or Java language server to get code completion suggestions.

Comment: I went through 

1. https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor/blob/master/test/playground.generated/customizing-the-appearence-tokens-and-colors.html 
2.  https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-css
3. monaco.editor.colorizeElement(document.getElementById('container'));

But no changes are reflected.

i tried  https://github.com/TypeFox/monaco-languageclient - but throwing errors